# Memory error caused by custom class function

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, methods

I have a class with a method that adds an element at a specified index.
I am trying to duplicate the last element of the vector and shifting every element once to the right so I can insert the new element to the given position.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
void Halmaz::add(const int index, const int num) {
    elemek.push_back(elemek.back());
    for (int i = elemek[elemek.size()-2]; i > index; i--){
        elemek[i] = elemek[i-1];
    }
    elemek[index] = num;
    //findMax();
}
```

Here is the error I get when trying to call the add() function:
Test code:

```
int main()
{
    Halmaz lista;
    lista.add(2);
    lista.add(3);
    lista.add(6);
    lista.add(1);
    lista.add(3);
    lista.print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << lista.getMax() << endl;;
    lista.add(66);
    lista.print();
    cout << lista.getMax() << endl;;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    lista.add(2,10); //the program stops here
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
 once 00C7CE88 is 201369893
```

Comment: What's wrong with [insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. You probably write out of bounds of the `elemek` vector. If you need more help then please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: I forgot to say that I know about insert() but I'd like to figure out this error message for learning purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = elemek[elemek.size()-2]; i > index; i--){
```

should be

```
for (int i = elemek.size()-2; i > index; i--){
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice this. Thanks!